# how to use for loop for such a functions?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, bar-chart

How can I shorten the code using "for" loop. I am just not able to use for for this function.

```
def f(year):
    
        if year==2017:
            plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[0,1:5])
    
        elif year==2016:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[1,1:5])
        elif year==2015:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[2,1:5])
        elif year==2014:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[3,1:5])
        elif year==2013:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[4,1:5])
        elif year==2012:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[5,1:5])
        elif year==2011:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[6,1:5])
        elif year==2010:
             plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[7,1:5])
```

Comment: For a start, I would recommend thinking about what areas of your function are repeated and which parts change. It looks like there are two main areas that change in your code, related to years and maybe index numbers of some sort. Could these be put into some sort of structure (maybe a `dict`) that could then be iterated over? It looks like the other lines of your code (the `plt.bar()` parts) seem largely similar to each other. Maybe these parts can be condensed?

Comment: I like your analysis and yes may be dictionary could be good idea. Will try to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop, use math:

```
def f(year):
    if year not in range(2010, 2018):
        return
    plt.bar(["NA_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales","Other_Sales"],abc.iloc[2017-year,1:5])
```

There's a straightforward linear relationship between the `year` and the variable part of the `iloc` subscript -- you can express that as `2017-year` and do this whole function in one line (plus an error check to catch invalid years).